# Classification of Banach Algebras?

Tags: operator-algebras, banach-algebras

Is there a classification theorem for Banach algebras, or even for Banach *algebras, similar to the GNS representation theorem for $C^*$-algebras?

If yes, please provide a reference where I can read about it.

If not, is there some Banach algebra which is NOT isomorphic to $B(X)$, where $X$ is a Banach space?

Comment: What you ask is not even true for $C^*$-algebras. What the GNS theorem says is that you can faithfully represent any $C^*$-algebra $A$ on some Hilbert space. Thus we get that $A$ is isomorphic to a $\textit{subalgebra}$ of $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$. For a Banach algebra you should be able to do a similar thing, but since you don't need $X$ to be a Hilbert space it should be easier. Let $B$ be the algebra. Let $B=X$, then $B$ acts on $X$ by left multiplication. This should embedd $B$ into $\mathcal{B}(B)$.

Answer (score 3):

Any finite dimensional Banach algebra of dimension not a square is not isomorphic to $B(X)$ for any Banach space $X$.

Comment: can you give a concrete example of such a finite dimensional banach algebra?

Comment: For example, the direct sum of $3$ copies of $\mathbb R$ (or $\mathbb C$) with the sup norm, which is isomorphic to the Banach algebra of continuous functions on a discrete space with three points.

Comment: (In fact, you can put *any* norm on $\mathbb R^3$ or $\mathbb C^3$)

Comment: @Amudhan  The space of upper triangle (2 x 2) matrices is another example.

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily shown that $B(X)$ has always nontrivial zero divisor.
Thus every Banach algebra which does not have zero divisor is another example. For example the disc algebra, the algebra of all holomorphic functions on the unit disk with continuous extension to the boundary.